# How to save the date and time last time when background process is executed

Tags: android, background-process

My application checks for new e-mails received when new mail is detected send notifications.
For now, I have been checking if the mail was received in the last 30 minutes to show it but the WorkManager sometimes stops working in the background(if you know why please tell me, do android somehow kill the process or my configuration is bad?) and mail notification will be missed.
Somehow I need to save data and time when the last notification was shown(background process is executed) but I don't know how can I keep that data in WorkManager when WorkManager stops working for some reason.

WorkManager call function:

```
  @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun startWorker(email: String, password: String) {

    if (enableMailNotifications == 1) {


        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

        val data = Data.Builder()
        data.put("email", email)
        data.put("password", password)


        val build: PeriodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            WorkerMan::class.java,
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES,

            )

            .addTag("WorkManager")
            .setInputData(data.build())
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(this)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("WorkManager", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, build)
    }else{
        println("WorkManager not called: Mail Notifications are turned off")
    }
}
```

WorkManager class:

```
class WorkerMan(private val mContext: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(mContext, workerParameters) {


    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "CheckResult")
    val email = inputData.getString("email")
    val password = inputData.getString("password")

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun doWork(): Result {


        println("WorkManager: Work called")
        Thread.sleep(5000)


        val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(Properties())
        val store = session.getStore("imaps")
        store.connect(
            "*****************",
            993,
            email,
            password
        )
        val inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX")
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)


        val messages = inbox.search(
            FlagTerm(Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false)
        )


        Arrays.sort(
            messages
        ) { m1: Message, m2: Message ->
            try {
                return@sort m2.sentDate.compareTo(m1.sentDate)
            } catch (e: MessagingException) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            }
        }





        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ")
        println("WorkManager Started")
        println("WorkMananager email: " + email)
        val current = LocalTime.now()
        println("WorkMananager time: " + current)
        println("Messages amount: " + messages.size)
        println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ")

        for (message in messages) {


            if (message.receivedDate.toInstant() >= Instant.now().minusMillis(1000 * 33 * 60)) {


                Thread.sleep(3000)
                println("=====================================================")
                println("NOTIFIKACIJA")

                var title = ""
                for (element in message.from) {
                    title += element.toString().substringAfter("<").substringBefore(">")
                    title += " "
                }
                println("Title :" + title)
                println("Subject :" + message.subject)
                println("Datum i vreme : " + message.receivedDate)

                title.replace("[", "")
                title.replace("]", "")



                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { token: String ->
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "retrieve token successful : $token")
                        try {
                            send(token, message.subject, title)
                        } catch (e: MessagingException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w("TAG", "token should not be null...")
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? -> }.addOnCanceledListener {}
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String> ->
                        Log.v(
                            "TAG",
                            "This is the token : " + task.result
                        )
                    }


//
            }


        }
        println("=====================================================")
        Log.d("WorkManager", "Job finished")

        return Result.Success();
    }

}


fun send(to: String?, body: String?, title: String?): String? {
    try {
        val apiKey =
            "*******************************************"
        val url = URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
        val conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        conn.doOutput = true
        conn.requestMethod = "POST"
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=$apiKey")
        conn.doOutput = true
        val message = JSONObject()
        message.put("to", to)
        message.put("priority", "high")
        val notification = JSONObject()
        notification.put("title", title)
        notification.put("body", body)
        message.put("notification", notification)
        val os = conn.outputStream
        os.write(message.toString().toByteArray())
        os.flush()
        os.close()
        val responseCode = conn.responseCode
        println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : $url")
        println("Post parameters : $message")
        println("Response Code : $responseCode")
        println("Response Code : " + conn.responseMessage)
        val `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(conn.inputStream))
        var inputLine: String?
        val response = StringBuffer()
        while (`in`.readLine().also { inputLine = it } != null) {
            response.append(inputLine)
        }
        `in`.close()

        // print result
        println(response.toString())
        return response.toString()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of Thread::sleep calls inside doWork methods. How much time doWork execution can take on your side?

You should pay attention that it have a limit - 10 minutes, from the java doc:

> A Worker is given a maximum of ten minutes to finish its
> execution and return a {@link androidx.work.ListenableWorker.Result}.
> After this time has expired, the Worker will be signalled to stop.

Also, possible situation when work was even not started, from the doc:

> Work is eligible for execution when all of its prerequisites are
> complete.  If any of it's prerequisites fail or are cancelled, the
> work will never run.

So maybe in your case it was not started?

Regarding saving timestamp - you can save it to permanent storage like database or [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

Comment: doWork execution lasts about 10-20 secs including all Thread::sleep calls.

Comment: What is actually meant by " prerequisites", is that constraints in startWorker function? My workmanager is always executed couple times so it's called. Maybe if the phone turns off internet for some time and I get error by trying to send requests?

Comment: As I undesrtand pre-requisites it's constraint that you specify in workRequest.

Comment: Now I removed all constraints but it's still the same.

Comment: This is the error i get: https://pastebin.com/BVxyA4uF and https://pastebin.com/ujYtNu60

Comment: I see, the issue related to execution network request on the main thread. You call send method inside FirebaseMessaging.token.SuccessListener. Please, pay attention to implementation of
public final Task<TResult> addOnSuccessListener(@NonNull OnSuccessListener<? super TResult> var1) {
        return this.addOnSuccessListener(TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD, var1);
    }

As you can see it set task executor - main thread. It means that all code that you put inside of the successListener callback will be executed on the main thread.

Comment: So, you need to care to run      send(token, message.subject, title) method  which you call inside the callback on the background thread.
There are a lot of aproaches to run it on the background thread: using Thread class or RxJava library. 
Just a summary: By default Workmanager is operating on the background thread, BUT FirebaseMessaging librrary is forcing to run code inside FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener  callbacks on the main thread.

Comment: I fixed NetworkOnMainThreadException by implementing firebase getToken in main Activity and passing it to worker class.
The problem now is the date, is there anything that i can use like editing input data or something so i can save lastCheckedDate, without loading it from sharedPreferences and etc.

Comment: Why don't you want to use  shared prefs?

Comment: In my app i am using datastore preferences but i cannot call methods for datastore prefs in my worker class

Comment: ` private fun observeNotificationsData() {
        settingsManager.lastCheckedDateFlow.asLiveData().observe(this, {
            this.lastCheckedDate = it

        })
    }`
"this" is Lifecycle Owner, how can i get Lifecycle Owner type in Worker class?

Comment: It's ot necessary conveert it to livedata. You can remove asLiveData() and work with Flow.

Comment: I succeed get LifeCycle Owner with: 

ProcessLifecycleOwner.get(

Comment: But anyways i got: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observe on a background thread